# Firebase Cloud Firestore - android application connection

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to connect the firestore db to my android application. I followed instructions but I can not create and instance of a Firestore db because "FirebaseFirestore" symbol can not resolved error pops up.

Here is my dependencies at build gradle (app) file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

and I also added this line to end of the build gradle  file :

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

and these are the dependencies at build gradle (project) file :

```
dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
             // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
```

and google's maven repository is defined like this:

```
 allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
```

What am i missing ? I also added google-services.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firebase database and its references use:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
```

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. Libraries that i need to use are still can't be found.

Comment: Ok did you try to add this too? compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
dependencies {  
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    // ...
}
```

Follow the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this gradle in Dependencies

```
dependencies {  
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.0'
    // ...
}
```